# How would I create a horizontal parallax which scrolls naturally?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

I have been looking into parallax effects and how to create them, but no where have I seen any information on how to create a parallax effect like on this webpage: https://www.fhoke.com

I have figured out regular vertical parallax, I've found information on horizontal parallax (which makes the entire webpage horizontal, not a section of it), but I can't find how to make something like in the above webpage where just a section moves horizontally while you scroll vertically.

How would I be able to do this with vanilla javascript css and html, or is this only possible with JQuery/Plugins?

Edit: Ive tried inspecting the code, but can't seem to find it either.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Like this
Sample Website -[Link](https://joseph-berry.webflow.io/)

here is the [post-mortem](https://dev.to/_martinwheeler_/creating-a-horizontal-scrolling-web-page-bonus-with-parallax-5ekm) for the above website

Comment: Right Idea, but again, those show parallax for the ENTIRE webpage, not just a single section like in the website I used as the example.

Comment: This seems to me like a custom slider written in JS, if you notice the scroll-bar it keeps going down..unlike as we see in the slider where the scroll-bar stays put, Also if we inspect the source you can clearly see the there are multiple ```<a href> ``` tags inside a single h2, and as we scroll the style property on H2 goes from 0 to this ```style="transform: translateX(-1742.5px);"```

Comment: Yes that's my question, how is this done?

Comment: I dont have a ready made code for this.. but if you wish to know the logic / how its done then then all you need to do is listen to thw scroll event when you hover on a certain element with id.. and then for each scroll you basically move your items from right to left which are set uaing display flex or in this case they used transform:traslateX from 0 to -1742.5px which i assume is the viewport width minus fixed container value

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was wondering.Would using the Intersection Observer be better than using an Event Listener?

Comment: Yes, using the intersects callback to located the elements on which we have to handle the scrollX prop.. i am not well versed with intersection Observer, as so far we only have used its callback a entry point for our methods / function.. there could be a more elegant way than to just listen the scroll event inside of intersection Observer